# Problem with adding checkbox to a view of flags with webform view

Tags: views, webforms, flags

So, I've been trying to implement a 'sample request' type webform using Flag, Webform, and Webform Views. The idea is to have a webform with a select list made from a view of Flags as implemented here through a custom module[Programmatic Sample Request, Drupal Steve](http://drupalsteve.com/node/57).

The issue I'm having is that I can't seem to get a checkbox to show up in the view. I have followed the instructions at the webform views documentation[Webform Views Docs](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform_view/plain/help/index.html?id=refs/heads/7.x-1.x) by creating a boolean field with a checkbox widget. I'm Flagging Commerce products.  I have even tried to add a boolean on Flags and add that into the view, but that didn't work either.  Not sure is this is a Flags, Commerce, or Webform Views issue, but I wanted to report this here and see if anyone had any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using drupal commerce (irrelevant), **session_api**, flags, views, webform4, custom content type (product display in my example), custom module.

Works even under ***anonymouse*** user

I think it's in select field settings.

**Called "Multiple":**

[image: multiple]

**webform_flags.module:**

```
    <?php 
 /**
 * Implements hook_webform_select_options_info().
 */
 function webform_flags_webform_select_options_info() {
    $items = array();
     if (function_exists('webform_flags_user_flag_sample_requests')) {
         $items['webform_flags_user_flag_sample_requests'] = array(
         'title' => t("User's flagged products"),
         'options callback' => 'webform_flags_user_flag_sample_requests',
         );
     }

    return $items;
 }

 function webform_flags_user_flag_sample_requests() {
     $view = views_get_view('user_flagged_products', TRUE);
     $options = array();
     if(isset($view)){
         $view->set_display('webform_options');
         $view->execute();

         if ($view->result) {
             //$row_class = $view->style_options['row_class'];
             //$attributes = $row_class ? " class='$row_class'" : '';
             foreach($view->result as $item) {
                //dpm($item->field_field_image);
                $options[$item->nid] = '<a>' . render($item->field_field_image[0]['rendered']) . $item->node_title .  '</a>';
         }
         }
         else {
            $options[0] = t("Nothing");
         }  
     }


    return $options;
 }
```

**View's settings:**
[image: view's settings]

Comment: See [result](http://i.imgur.com/MgyBc8b.png). Can't post more than 2 links in post. =)

Comment: This is a well-documents and thorough, answer!